# In WP8, is it possible for ListPicker not to "push away" other UI elements?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, listpicker

Currently, I have:

```
<StackPanel>
    <toolkit:ListPicker
         Header="Rating"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Ratings}"
         SelectedIndex="1"
         SelectionChanged="RatingSelectionChanged"/>
<TextBlock
          x:Name="RatingSelection"
          CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Whenever I press on the ListPicker, it would expand and push away the Textblock. Is there a way such that the textblock will stay in place and would simply be under the ListPicker?

**Update 1:**
Following Will's suggestion of layering two grid layouts over each other, the issue still persists, the expansion of the listpicker moves other UI elements, more specifically the buttons moves as the ListPicker is expanded. Also, I've included the actual code I am using:

```
               <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    

                        <Button 
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Content="Save" 
                            Height="71" 
                            x:Name="SaveButton" 
                            Width="123" 
                            Click="SaveButton_Click"/>
                         <Button 
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Content="Generate"
                            Height="71" 
                            x:Name="GenerateButton" 
                            Width="154" 
                            Click="GenerateButton_Click"/>

                          <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                               </Grid.RowDefinitions>       

                               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                         <toolkit:ListPicker
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             x:Name="Auth_ListPicker"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                             Width="156"
                             SelectedIndex="1"
                             SelectionChanged="Auth_ListPicker_SelectionChanged"/>
                          </Grid>            
           </Grid>
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: StackPanels always make room for the controls contained within.  I'd layer two Grids over each other, the one with the listpicker layered over the one below, so that controls contained within overlay everything below.  Just leave room so that the control in its normal state leaves the area blank.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Will. Unfortunately, the ListPicker still pushes away the UI element below it (namely an image). Do you have any other suggestions such that the listPicker would just overlap the image?

Comment: Yes, don't put anything below the ListPicker in a StackPanel, as it will be moved down to make room.  You have to put them in two different containers, or use a different container like a Canvas.

Comment: By design ListPickers are supposed to act that way. Alternatively you can force ListPicker to be opened in full mode. (That will open the list picker items in a new window)